# How to get a package installed through dism from the staged to installed state

Tags: windows

I have installed the Microsoft-Windows-Media-Format-Package using dism (dism /online /add-package /packagepath: /ignorecheck)

and then removed the package, and now if I re-install the package the state of the package goes to staged.

How do I move the package's state from staged to installed?

Comment: Have you tried `dism /enable-feature`?

Comment: If I use /get-features on the package I cannot see any features for the package

Answer (score 0):

To change the state from staged to installed you must do an add-capability

Like to change Dot net framework 3.5 from staged to installed you would do:

Dism /online /add-capability /CapabilityName:NetFX3~~~~